# skin Suit modelling for a super hero . Need some workflow

Tags: modeling, modifiers, cloth-simulation

[image: image of my work] Guys, I am trying to make *[Black Adam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Adam)* in Blender. I have made the body. But I don't know how to make the suit. I have tried using the cloth physics with stitching but that was very laggy.

Please suggest me some workflow to make the skinsuit. Also, I am just 2 months into Blender so pretty much I am a noob. Therefore I have just applied a material directly over the body and my model is looking weird. So please suggest to me some workflow to model the suit after modeling the body.

Comment: you should use the skin as the suit, shouldn't you?

Comment: So what do you exactly want it to look like, maybe a reference image to what you want to get would really help.

Comment: Is this a final render? What are these squares on his suit? Where are they coming from?